# How can i unlink file for removal in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I a using this code for image removal when i delete the entity

```
  /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($this->filenameForRemove)
        {
            unlink ( $this->filenameForRemove );
        }
    }
```

But the problem is if i don't have the image there then it throws exception like this

```
Warning: unlink(/home/site/../../../../uploads/50343885699c5.jpeg) [<a href='function.unlink'>function.unlink</a>]: No such file or directory i
```

Is there any way that if file is not there or directory is not there it should skip this step and still deletes the entity

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`file_exists`](http://php.net/file_exists) to make sure the file actually exists and [`is_writable`](http://php.net/is_writable) to make sure you have permission to remove it.

```
if ($this->filenameForRemove)
{
    if (file_exists($this->filenameForRemove) &&
        is_writable($this->filenameForRemove))
    {
        unlink ( $this->filenameForRemove );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update

Symfony has introduced the The Filesystem Component. You can check the docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html). It says: `The Filesystem component provides basic utilities for the filesystem.`

For example you can check if the file path/directory exists before deleting your file like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;


$filesystem = new Filesystem();
$oldFilePath = '/path/to/directory/activity.log'

if($filesystem->exists($oldFilePath)){
    $filesystem->remove($oldFilePath); //same as unlink($oldFilePath) in php
}
```